# Rotating DrawingBrush from center using RotateTransform

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a UserControl of a compass that I wish to rotate.  I'm trying to rotate it from center, and Google's finding plenty of references to using  `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"` to achieve this.  But this is not working for some reason.  It's only rotating the UserControl with the corner as origin.

If I set `CenterX="150"` and `CenterY="150"` inside the UserControl, it works.  But then I also have to set the height and width of the UserControl in the main window to 300.

How can I get the UserControl to be rotated from its center point regardless of height and width settings set when calling the UserControl?  I would also prefer to set the RenderTransformOrigin inside the UserControl rather than when calling it.

(Simplified) UserControl XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Poseidon.Views.CompassUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Poseidon.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DrawingBrush x:Key="Compass_ver1">
                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    <DrawingGroup>
                        <DrawingGroup.Children>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="M 375.286,151.366C 486.487,151.366 576.634,241.513 576.634,352.714C 576.634,463.915 486.487,554.061 375.286,554.061C 264.085,554.061 173.939,463.915 173.939,352.714C 173.939,241.513 264.085,151.366 375.286,151.366 Z "/>
                            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M 375.286,151.366C 486.487,151.366 576.634,241.513 576.634,352.714C 576.634,463.915 486.487,554.061 375.286,554.061C 264.085,554.061 173.939,463.915 173.939,352.714C 173.939,241.513 264.085,151.366 375.286,151.366 Z ">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Thickness="0.755907" LineJoin="Round" Brush="#FF000000"/>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFFFFFF" Geometry="M 382.484,188.872C 472.971,192.847 543.103,269.425 539.128,359.912C 535.153,450.399 458.575,520.531 368.088,516.556C 277.601,512.58 207.469,436.003 211.444,345.516C 215.42,255.029 291.997,184.897 382.484,188.872 Z "/>
                            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M 382.484,188.872C 472.971,192.847 543.103,269.425 539.128,359.912C 535.153,450.399 458.575,520.531 368.088,516.556C 277.601,512.58 207.469,436.003 211.444,345.516C 215.42,255.029 291.997,184.897 382.484,188.872 Z ">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Thickness="0.755907" LineJoin="Round" Brush="#FF000000"/>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="M 375.286,227.352L 389.511,202.805L 403.736,178.258L 375.286,178.258L 346.836,178.258L 361.061,202.805L 375.286,227.352 Z "/>
                            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M 375.286,227.352L 389.511,202.805L 403.736,178.258L 375.286,178.258L 346.836,178.258L 361.061,202.805L 375.286,227.352 Z ">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Thickness="0.755907" LineJoin="Round" Brush="#FF000000"/>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup.Children>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            </DrawingBrush>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource Compass_ver1}">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding FlightData.Value.Heading}" />
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Main window XAML:

```
<local:CompassUserControl DataContext="{Binding Rov}" Height="100" Width="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
```

Comment: Your `RotateTransform` is set on the `Rectangle` inside your control, so why did you set `RenderTransformOrigin` on the `CompassUserControl` rather than on this rectangle? Either move `RenderTransformOrigin` to `Rectangle`, or move `RotateTransform` to the `CompassUserControl`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  Another "Ahaa!" moment.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RenderTransformOrigin` property gets or sets the center point of any transform declared by `RenderTransform` property, relative to the bounds of the element to which you have applied the transform: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin(v=vs.110).aspx

So - as suggested by @Maxim - you should set the `RenderTransformOrigin` property of the `Rectangle` element inside your `UserControl`:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource Compass_ver1}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding FlightData.Value.Heading}" />
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and the information.  It worked like a charm.